Very strange problem with occasional 404 errors
I'm having a very strange effect on my website with occasional 404 errors.
First of all: This is not a normal problem with redirect rules or htaccess. So please don't make comments like "check your rewrites". I know pretty well what I'm doing and can say with certainty that the following effect is not normal.
The 404 problem does not occur all the time and only occurs on pages. It doesn't occur here:

Posts
WooCommerce products
Learndash courses
Taxonomy pages
and any other type of content
not even on the homepage
not on the page that is set up for the WooCommerce shop
not on the shopping cart and checkout page
not on a site used for the wpForo forum

Yes, I use a lot of heavyweight plugins, but the server handles them very well and at a decent speed.
Normally everything works. But once in a while WordPress goes into this weird 404 mode and just stops displaying normal pages.
Initially the problem only appeared after I updated plugins. Not with every plugin, but tends to be the case with “heavy” plugins. Almost certainly this always happened after updating Yoast SEO.
Now after changing my theme from Twenty Thirteen to Astra Pro, the problem is also caused by other triggers. I can't say exactly what triggers it.
To display the pages again (at least until the next occurrence), the following helps:

deactivate and reactivate one of the heavy plugins (Yoast SEO had a 100% chance of working, but occasionally LearnDash too)
Re-save permalinks

As I said, it's not a problem with htaccess or something similar, as everything normally works. The server is Nginx and my host Raidboxes handles this globally for tens of thousands of websites.
I found a possible clue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28007791
However, the memory limit is already 2048 MB and is not even close to being exhausted. Max script execution time is 1 minute and cannot be the problem (404 comes immediately).
Caching is regulated by my host, but has no impact on the effect. If I disable it, the problem still occurs.
Deactivating plugins cannot be a solution either. Firstly, I need the plugins installed (I know that I should be economical with this and try to avoid additional plugins at all costs, but what has to be, has to be). Also, the problem already occurred (after plugin updates) when I hadn't installed WooCommerce, wpForo, Learndash and a few others yet.
WordPress is always in the latest version (it has been for years), and the PHP version is always as up to date as my host allows (currently 8.2).
Because I now had an urgent need for action (it's just annoying to have to re-save the permalinks every 15 minutes to make the pages available again, not to mention the poor user experience), I added a workaround to my Astra child theme's functions.php:
add_action('template_redirect', 'hkp_404_workaround');
function hkp_404_workaround ()
{
    if (is_404())
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['redirect404']))
        {
            $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            $redirect_to = $url . (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY) ? '&' : '?') . 'redirect404=1';

            //flush_rewrite_rules(); // no effect
            delete_option('rewrite_rules'); // works great

            wp_redirect($redirect_to);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

Here a hook is added to the output of the 404 page, deleting the rewrite_rules (forcing WordPress to recreate them) and then redirecting to the same URL that was called. The site is then back – works very well as a temporary workaround! An additional parameter ensures that in the event of a real 404 error, the whole thing doesn't end up in an endless redirect loop. I removed additional logging from the above code for greater clarity.
As I said, it works for now, but I would like to find the root cause and fix it.
I would be grateful for any clues as to how I could find the cause.
Unfortunately, I can't do any debug output or anything similar in WordPress Core because my host doesn't offer write permissions (Core directories are only integrated via symlinks). However, I could add something to wp_config.php.

IF one of the plugins is in fact causing the issue and you can't disable any of the plugins then I have bad news for you.  This is going to be next to impossible to diagnose unless the plugin developers themselves push another update and fix it and it's going to be impossible to fix if unless the plugin developers fix it.
If your site is that mission critical and important that you can't deactivate plugins, then why not spin up a test environment?  Why not spin up a staging or a dev environment and test disabling plugins on there to see if you can isolate the issue.

@TonyDjukic I'm not so sure that a plugin causes the problem. Just updating some plugins triggers it, but there can also be other triggers. Currently this happens 2-3 times per hour, which must be caused by page views or cron jobs.
I have a staging environment and can test pretty anything there (this is created as a fresh clone of the live site whenever I need it). The problem is: it almost never happens on staging. There is no live traffic and also plugin updates don't cause it there, so it is nearly impossible to reproduce this on staging.
